# Who carried the bow and arrows of Hercules

Tags: greek

Who carried the bow and see w of Hercules after he died?

Comment: I hope I've correctly understood what your asking, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

According to Herodotus, (one of) Hercules bows was inherited by his son Scythes, who is said to be the forebear of the Scythians:

> Hereupon he strung one of his bows- up to that time he had carried two- and showed her how to fasten the belt. Then he gave both bow and belt into her hands. Now the belt had a golden goblet attached to its clasp. So after he had given them to her, he went his way; and the woman, when her children grew to manhood, first gave them severally their names. One she called Agathyrsus, one Gelonus, and the other, who was the youngest, Scythes. Then she remembered the instructions she had received from Hercules, and, in obedience to his orders, she put her sons to the test. Two of them, Agathyrsus and Gelonus, proving unequal to the task enjoined, their mother sent them out of the land; Scythes, the youngest, succeeded, and so he was allowed to remain. From Scythes, the son of Hercules, were descended the after kings of Scythia
>   <sub>Herodotus, [Histories 4](http://classics.mit.edu/Herodotus/history.4.iv.html)</sub>

To clarify, this is a *Greek* legend about the origin of the Scythians, *not* a Scythian legend.

This is a reference to the abilities of the Scythians in archery, especially horse archery, a skill which would continue to be key to many groups of eurasian steppe nomads (ex. the Mongols, the Huns, etc.) for a very long time.